# FindByNameAsync throws a Drop Drop Database error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem that is confusing me, so I thought I should ask the community. I have implemented the EF user authentication functionality which works well from time to time, however from time to time, this line of code throws a Drop Database error.

`var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);`

I am not sure what could be causing the error and where I must check when this happens. Also why would it try to drop the database when all I am doing is selecting a record from the database?

***UPDATE***

After reading the comment, I thought I should try add more meat to my question.

I am trying to authenticate the user using the following piece of code.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var securityService = GetFromContext<ISecurityService>(context);
                var logger = GetFromContext<ILogger>(context);
                var user = await securityService.AuthenticateAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

                ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user);
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
                context.Validated(ticket);
                context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(oAuthIdentity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Removed for brevity
            }
        }
```

The method AuthenticateUser looks like the following:

```
public async Task<SecureUser> AuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password, bool sendOtp = true)
        {
            var user = await GetUserByNameAsync(userName);
            return user;
        }
```

This calls the originally asked method on the following code:

```
public async Task<SecureUser> GetUserByNameAsync(string userName)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            return user;
        }
```

The method throws the following exception when called.

[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNINs.png)

Error message as a string

`Cannot drop database XXXX because it is currently in use.`

Unfortunately for security reasons I cannot share the database name.

The full stack trace is below

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<DropDatabase>b__0(DbConnection conn)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.<UsingConnection>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DropDatabase(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, String databaseName)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbDeleteDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Delete()
   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Rica.Security.SecurityService`1.<GetUserByNameAsync>d__22.MoveNext() in C:\Repos\RICA\Rica.Security\SecurityService.cs:line 301
```

I hope the meat I added explains my problem slightly better.

Comment: What you posted isn't an EF method, it's a UserManager method that may or may *not* be using a database underneath. It won't try to drop any databases either. Post the *full exception text* (ie message, inner exceptions, callstakck - the entire result of Exception.ToString()). `throws a Drop Database error.` doesn't explain anything, especially when only reading is involved. Perhaps your code is trying to execute an EF migration script. Or perhaps you have an actual call that deletes and rebuilds a database. We can't guess what *your* code does

Comment: Are you using the asp net core 3.1 identity server, and can you add the full error?

Comment: I have updated my question with more code example and exceptions I am getting.

Comment: Can you also post the ?Exception itself as a String at the top of the Stack Trace you are already showing?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe edited right below the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the fact that I have added a migration onto the application before running the Update-Database command.

So the model is dirty, and because of it being dirty, there is a command that EF has that is called DropDatabseIfModelChanges which tries to drop the database, however because the application is running and a connection has been established, I receieve that error.

I solved it but running my Update-Database command and the error was solved.